# Resistance measured low in constant DC voltage supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, resistance, voltmeter

I have a DC power supply, which I have connected to an electrical circuit on a breadboard whose total or equivalent resistance is to be measured. The power supply comes with a voltage and current display. Now whenever I measure the resistance by taking the ratio of voltage (V) and current (I) from the display, the resistance $$R=V/I$$ is found to be smaller than the actual one (tested theoretically and also by measuring using a multimeter).

[image]

For instance, as shown in the image here, the voltage (V) is 14.29 Volts and current (I) is .055 Amperes, which means resistance is R=V/I=259.82 Ohms where my actual resistance should be around 271 Ohms.

What can be majorly responsible for this discrepancy, the display's voltmeter circuit's internal resistance? Or can there be a more complex reason since the circuit is supposed to have digital elements inside (can any research paper be cited in that case)?

Comment: That measurement is within 5%.  What is the stated accuracy of your meters?

Comment: Ditto, the stated accuracy of those resistors? (or the colour of their tolerance bands). This is where you learn about error budgets : there's a number of error sources here, and now you get to analyze each in turn. For one, if the current measurement is off by 1 digit, that alone contributes almost 2% error.

Comment: As mentioned, the overall resistance has been measured with a multimeter and the error was in the miliOhms order.  So resistors being the source of the error should be most unlikely. Let me rephrase my question: Assuming that the circuit on the board is correct (as tested with a multimeter), what could be the possible sources of error? Can one list a few?